# Call function in ng-change when multiple times was same option clicked

Tags: html, angularjs, select

I've got this code:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.currentOption;
  $scope.showWindow = false;

  $scope.myOptions = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'This opens the window'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Option 2'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Option 3'
  }];

  $scope.showOption = function() {
    if ($scope.currentOption.id == 1) {
      $scope.showWindow = true;
    }
    console.log($scope.currentOption);
  }

  $scope.closeWindow = function() {
    $scope.showWindow = false;
  }
});
```

```css
.filterWindow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <select ng-options="option as option.name for option in myOptions" ng-change="showOption()" ng-model="currentOption"></select>

  <div ng-if="showWindow" class="filterWindow">
    <button ng-click="closeWindow()">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've got a dropdown with three options. When I click on an option, it calls me a function with `ng-change`. The function is just called, when I click on another option in the dropdown list because of the `ng-change`. I would like to call the function every time I click on an option, also on the same twice in a row. So for example: When I click on 'Option 1', it should call the function (this works). When I click again on the same option (in this case 'Option 1'), so it should call the function again (this doesn't work, because the ng-change didn't detect a change in the dropdown). I tried it with `ng-click`, but then it calls the functions also when I open the dropdown, this is bad for me. The reason I need this is, in my web application one of my options opens a window, where I can filter a list. So when I filter it and than would like to change the filter critireas, it should open again this window by clicking on the same option which is selected in this moment. That's why the `ng-click` isn't a good solution, because this window would open also when I open the dropdown. I hope this is clear. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** So I builded now in the snippet example a window. When you click on the option which opens the window, it works when you do this the first time. Then you close the window, but don't change the option before... After you closed the window, the option which opens the window is still selected. When you click again on it, it don't open the window, becaus there was no change, so `ng-change` call for the function don't work... How to force this?

Thanks

Comment: PLEASE CHECK THE EDITED SNIPPET AND THE DESCRIPTION FOR IT....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this function

```
$scope.showOption = function() { //Check whether drop down has any selected value
   if($scope.currentOption) { 
      console.log($scope.currentOption);
   }
}
```

Use `ng-click` instead `ng-change`
And remain the click event. It will not console when you open the drop down but event will trigger. Check [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/m6orgO6MffQVzJmXtg1t?p=preview) plunker

Comment: Hi, can you make a working fiddle? I don't understand how this should help me...?

Comment: Click will trigger on each call but it will not work until and unless `$scope.currentOption` has ny selected value in it :)